# Only using certain parts of Autocomplete from Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I'm trying to use Material-UI's component `<Autocomplete/>`

However, I want to remove certain functionality that isn't necessarily customizable according to the API. For example I want to remove the multiselect filter tags and shown below. Would it be possible just to take the logic of passing in a list and being able to search/autocomplete?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code also?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Yeah it's just the Autocomplete from material-ui - https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Comment: For multiple selections to be false there is property called as mulitple , you can set it to false.